# C# Regex Replace Pattern (Replace String) Return $1

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I'm currently working with parsing some data from SQL Server and I'm in need of help with a Regex.

I have an assembly in Sql Server 2005 that helps me Replace strings using C# **Regex.Replace()** Method.

I need to parse the following.

```
    Strings:

    CAD 90890

    (CAD 90892)

    CAD G67859

    CAD 34G56

    CAD 3S56.

    AX CAD 890990

    CAD 783783 MX

    Needed Results:

    90890

    90892

    G67859

    34G56

    3S56

    890990

    783783 

SELECT TOP 25 CADCODE, dbo.RegExReplace(CADCODE, '*pattern*', '$1')
FROM dbo.CADCODES
WHERE CADCODE LIKE '%CAD%'
```

I need to get the proceeding string after the CAD word until it hits a white-space or anything that not a number or digit. I managed to get the digits but it really fails on others. I'm trying to get it to work but I can't find a real solution.

Thanks in advance.

**Updated to reflect new Strings**

AX CAD 890990

CAD 783783 MX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(\w+)\W*$
```

The pattern matches the last word - made of alphanumeric (and underscores).
Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/1zWQQVLZy1

Another option is to find a word with at least one digit - this one can match anywhere on the string, so you may need to handle multiple matches. In this case, you can add a capturing group around the whole pattern, or replace using `$&`.

```
[a-zA-Z_]*\d\w*
```

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/XUrFNuPQUv

If you can't match (`Regex.Match`) and must use `Regex.Replace`, you can match the entire string start to end and replace it with the group you need:

```
RegExReplace(CADCODE, '^.*\b([a-zA-Z_]*\d\w*)\b.*$', '$1')
```

Comment: What happens if some of the strings do not start with CAD, but are followed by alphanumeric characters?

Comment: @Callum Rogers - I capture them anyway, the question doesn't define whether that bit is important or not. I may ask you the same - what if the OP wants to capture in any case?

Comment: [a-zA-Z_]*\d\w* Matches perfectly what I need to understand is how to get the output $1 for the replace, since I need to eliminate CAD completely.

Comment: well, if you want just the word following the CAD..., I dont know if I'd use Regex.Replace. You could just use Regex.Match and it would bring back the word that matched. OR..you could use (?=<something>), which matches a prefix, but excludes it from the output.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after:

```
^\W*\w*CAD\w*\W*(\w+)\W*$
```

The regex has to match the whole string so RegExReplace can replace it with `$1`, effectively stripping off the unwanted parts.

EDIT: Let me back up and make sure I've got this right.  Because of the

```
WHERE CADCODE LIKE '%CAD%'
```

in your query, you already know every string contains the sequence `CAD`.  That being the case, there's no need to complicate the regex by matching that sequence again.  This should be all you need:

```
^.*?(\w+)\W*$
```

Comment: Great approach and It works I just have a slight problem that wasn't on scope. I found out that I will have strings with "AX CAD 098909" instead of CAD as the beginning and also strings after "CAD 098909 MX".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?:\(CAD\)|CAD)\s+?([\dA-Z]+)
```

You can get the result from the capture group number `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with regex is that it's always easy to get a good pattern if you have a limited sample set.

In your case, you use:
\w{4}\w*

which just says, 4 alphanumerics, followed by 0 or more alphanumerics, so all the CAD sections would not match, nor would spaces or ().

Comment: The problem with Regex is that it's a pain in the butt. Anyhow CAD can have multiple digits and even a word but what I really need is the WORD after CAD until it ends with anything that's not a number or letter from the alphabet [A-Za-z]. Just extract it and have it as an output in $1.

Comment: so if I'm understanding you right, you'll have CAD followed by some stuff, then 1 or more spaces, then you want the word after that? How about: CAD\w*\s+(\w+)

Comment: See @Alan Moore approach it works mine was similar in the way that I was matching words but I couldn't get an output group. But as he suggests you need to match first the whole string first.